# Downloading Mapbox style packs returns a cancellation error

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android, mapbox-ios

I am trying to download multiple style packs for offline use by following the example in the [Maps SDK for iOS documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/guides/offline/#download-a-style-pack).

In the documentation example, the completion handler handles cancellation errors differently than all other types of errors, like so:

```
if case StylePackError.canceled = error {
    handleCancelation()
} else {
    handleFailure()
}
```

When I call `loadStylePack()` multiple times simultaneously with the same `styleURI`, the completion handler is called with a `canceled` `StylePackError`.

Is it safe to assume that a cancellation error will occur when attempting to download a `styleURI` that is already being downloaded? I was unable to find documentation indicating under what conditions a cancellation error can occur.

In other words, should I call `loadStylePack()` again if it's error type is `canceled`, or can I assume the data is already loaded?

My question applies to both the iOS and Android SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think it's safe to assume that. I also encountered this behaviour.
Same behaviour is also when loading a tile region for offline use and this is included in the documentation:

> If there is already a pending loading operation for the tile region with the given id, the pending loading operation will fail with an error of Canceled type.

Please check `loadTileRegion(forId:loadOptions:progress:completion:)` method from `TileStore`.

I can only assume that it's the same handling based on the above mentioned.

I'm using iOS SDK 10.10.0, not sure about Android or other iOS SDK versions.